# 2-rail and caesar cipher using C

Tags: c, encryption

I've been given a homework to encrypt AND decrypt a word using Caesar and 2-rail ciphers. Though I understand the concept, I am having a huge trouble putting it into code.

**Exercise** 
*Use the word "Alexandrossa" and encrypt it using 2-rail fence method and then to Caesar by 2 letter forward (ie. A becomes C, or X becomes Z)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    char a[2][6] = {'A', 'L', 'E', 'X', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'R', 'O', 'S', 'S', 'A'};
    char row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 6; ++col)
        {
            printf("%c", a[row][col]);
        }

        printf("\n", a[row][col]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It displays as...

> ALEXAN
>
> DROSSA

But I can't make the output display as this:

> AEADOS
>
> LXNRSA
>
> Result:
>   AEADOSLXNRSA

If anyone can help me complete this program and at least give me some hint on completing the Caesar Cipher part without problem, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Caesar cipher hint: chars are just numbers.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils One more hint: Numbers that stand for characters need not be consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the string and just manipulate the string according to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[2][6] = {'A', 'L', 'E', 'X', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'R', 'O', 'S', 'S', 'A'};
    char row, col;
    printf("Rail cipher:\n");
    for (row = 0; row < 1; ++row) {
        for (col = 0; col < 12; col += 2) {
            printf("%c", a[row][col]);
        }
        //printf("\n");
        for (col = 0; col < 12; col += 2) {
            printf("%c", a[row][col + 1]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nCaesar cipher:\n");
    for (row = 0; row < 12; ++row) {
        char c = a[0][row];
        c = (char) (c + 2);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code just encrypts the string with your two methods. Decrypting is done similarly by just reversing the algorithm.

**Test**

> ```
> $ ./a.out
> Rail cipher:
> AEADOSLXNRSA
> Caesar cipher:
> CNGZCPFTQUUC
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: Yeees! Thank you! I really appreciate the help! :D